# JQuery Slimscroll issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, slimscroll

```js
      $(document).ready(function(e){ 
$('#boxL').slimscroll({
    color: '#212121',
    position:'right',
     distance : '0px',
    size: '10px',
    height: '800px',
    width:'200px',
    alwaysVisible: true
});
});

    $(document).ready(function(e){ 
$('#boxC').slimscroll({
    color: '#212121',
    position:'right',
     distance : '0px',
    size: '10px',
    height: '800px',
    width:'200px',
    alwaysVisible: true
});
});



    $(document).ready(function(e){ 
$('#boxR').slimscroll({
    color: '#212121',
    position:'right',
     distance : '0px',
    size: '10px',
    height: '800px',
    width:'200px',
    alwaysVisible: true
});
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;  
}

.bloqueL {
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding:10px;
display:inline-block;

}
.bloqueC {
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding:10px;
display:inline-block;


}
.bloqueR {
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding:10px;
display:inline-block;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://madeindreams.ca/JS/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="boxL" class="bloqueL" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="dragLeave(event)">
    x<br>
    x<br>
    x<br>
    x<br>
    x<br>
    x<br>
    x<br>
    x<br>
    x<br>
    x<br>
    x<br>
    x<br>
    x<br>
    x<br>
  </div>
  
  <div id="boxC" class="bloqueC" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="dragLeave(event)">
      </div>
  
    <div id="boxR" class="bloqueR" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="dragLeave(event)">
      </div>
</body>
```

I have found [Slimscroll](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll) and tried it. On the site where they show a working demo the scroll bar is attached to the container. But when I try it. the scroll bar is all the way to the right.

I have 3 containers and eventually on the page

I would like my 3 containers to be aligned on the same line. But because of slimscroll they are one after each other.

Even if I set the position to absolute it is not working.

Comment: can you create a fiddler

Comment: I try but for some reason its not working in the fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the `height: '100%',` option. You can set this only if the element's parent has `height` style. In this case the element's parent is the `body` and the `body` has no `height`.

You have 2 ways to fix this:

1. Set the `body` height.
2. Change the option from `100%` to whatever you want like `100px` like in the example below: (Also, remove the unnecessary `css` code. The plugin take care about it.)

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) { 
  $('.bloqueL').slimscroll({
    color: '#212121',
    size: '10px',
    height: '100px',
    alwaysVisible: true
  });
});
```

```css
/*.bloqueL{
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
height:100px;
width: 420px;
min-height: 10px;
border:1px solid #000000;
overflow-x: hidden;  
overflow-y: hidden; 
}*/

* {
  box-sizing:border-box;  
}

.bloqueL {
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://madeindreams.ca/JS/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="boxL" class="bloqueL" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="dragLeave(event)">
    x<br>
    x<br>
    x<br>
    x<br>
    x<br>
    x<br>
    x<br>
    x<br>
    x<br>
    x<br>
    x<br>
    x<br>
    x<br>
    x<br>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for the repply. In my case it will be more complicated then that since that the #boxL container is first; Dynamically updated, Second; animated, However i got a workaround solution. I am using the slimscroll distance option to place the bar at 402px from the left.

Comment: I don't understand how this solve your problem but I'm happy for you.. Maybe you can update your snippet so it will looks like your site, or post your public URL (if you have one) and maybe I could suggest you a solution..

Comment: Just found out that it does not. I cant add a second bar to the page this way.

Comment: `Just found out that it does not` which one? Can you update your snippet so I could see the problem?

Comment: yes I actually found what is wrong. My width is not being applyed and my boxL is 100% of the page so that why my bar is all the way right. Updating now

Comment: Got it now! The css as to be in the slimscroll param.

Comment: The thing is when i add another scrollbar the second container get placed under the #boxL.

Comment: I have updated my post so you can see what i need. It only work for one container. I have 3 containers and they get placed one after the other instead of next to each other.

Comment: That's because the plugin create a `div` wrapper `.slimScrollDiv`. By default, his `display` is `block`. If you want that they will be side by side, add to the `css`: `.slimScrollDiv{float:left;}`